# How To Get Current Application URL Without using Request object (ex:HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority) ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, url, c#-4.0

I trying to get current url while executing the automatic job scheduling.
Request object is null while executing  automatic job scheduling.

My code:

```
string imgpath = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority + "/App_Themes/login_logo.png";
```

Request is `null(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority =null)`. So I am not able to get the current url.

Anyother way to do this?

Comment: can u try to get this url as parameter from calling object/class ?

Comment: yes,thanks ijaz..you know the reason behind this?

Comment: actually Request object is only available in the process running under IIS (web server) , your job scheduling is running under OS service process not controlled by IIS , so the point where u call job from ur IIS-web method, there u can pass this request as param to job-service.